# Fixing load-use hazard issue in pipeline (MIPS)

Tags: mips, pipeline, forwarding, pipelining

I have been working on some low level programming with 5 stage pipelining. But I hit a snag.

Assuming this diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbe0C.png
and the mips code:

lw $4,1000($6)

sw $4,2000($6)

what would actually happen? I assumed there would be bubbles, i counted two bubbles proceeding the ID stage.

Can we fix it by adding inputs to the new forwarding unit? Where can I add mux's and new datapaths to to avoid bubble+errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there would be two bubbles.

Assuming **data forwarding:**

```
1. IF ID EX MM WB

2.    IF S  S  ID EX MM WB
```

*(S means stall or bubble).*

There is **no way you can 'fix' it** because in any case you have to wait for the end of the **MM** stage to have the value at 1000($6). It could even be worse without data forwarding where you would have to wait until the **WB** stage, meaning 3 stalls.

Only way to **prevent** such behaviour is to have smart compilers that will schedule those two instructions in a different way (i.e *space* them by adding others in-between).

Note that as it is, the program has **no real purpose** (*get value at memory address [1000+Regs[$6]], and copy it at address [2000+Regs[$6]]*)

Comment: You could use forwarding from MM/WB intermediate register to ID/EX intermediate register. The you would need only 1 stall right?

Answer (score 0):

You need MEM to ALU forwarding